# Why can't we run through walls like Harry Potter?

Tags: atomic-physics, matter

This is a very simple and stupid question but ever since I watched the first Harry Potter and saw Harry and his friends run through a wall at King's Cross Station I have wondered what keeps us from just running through objects or falling through the floor? Is there some fundamental physical law/concept that prevents us from doing this?

Comment: [Related question.](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/126512/)

Answer (score 0):

Of course there is. A wall, or a floor, is some chemical construction and it is in the solid state of aggregation because of stiff bonds between an atom/molecule and its neighbors - look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_structure#Lattice_systems) for instance, to see a crystal structure. The higher this energy is, the more difficult is to break the material. To penetrate the wall/floor you have to break this bond in a region, i.e. to invest a higher energy than that binding energy.