# Is atom mostly empty space or not?

Tags: atomic-physics, vacuum, atoms

I have read in many science popularizing articles that atoms are mostly empty space but on more research I have found that that is not the case since what interacts generally with the surrounding is the cloud of electrons or more precisely the roaming electrons which have a non-zero probability of being anywhere in principle.

This explanation is not clear to me.

Consider a hydrogen atom. The nucleus is of the order of a few fermis while the elctron on average moves at around 100,000 distances from it.
This looks like a lot of empty space.

What is a clear explanation of this?

Comment: This [closely related answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/109020/44126) says basically "no, they're not."

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/267357/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Will a crude mass density profile with radius from the center answer your question? You seem to have access to the relevant numbers.

Comment: Can you be more specific *what* about the "electron cloud" explanation is not clear to you?

Comment: I would phrase it as: the atom is always mostly empty space, but none of the space in the atom is always empty.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If particles are points, then aren't atoms empty space?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/267357)

Comment: @Roger Vadim Yes it does. So basically the Pauli exlusion and normal em repulsion makes that "empty region" inaccessible. In other words, loosely speaking the electron cloud can literally be taken as a hard shaped impentrable thing. Is that correct?

Comment: A more precise way would be ( I hope) to say that the probabilty of the overlap or passing through is really really small if not absolutely zero. One can probably calculate this small number for two isolated hydrogen atoms confined in a finte volume.